# Using Kotlin Sealed Classes for routing to different screens

Tags: android, kotlin, android-mvvm, sealed-class

Is it a good idea to create sealed classes as such:

```
sealed class Route<out T: Any> {
    data class ToRoute1<out T : Any>(val data: T) : Route<T>()
    data class ToRoute2<out T : Any>(val data: T) : Route<T>()
    data class ToRoute3<out T : Any>(val data: T) : Route<T>()
}
```

So the `Route` seal class will define all the possible destination that current screen could "route to". So for example "LoginScreen" can have the following sealed class:

```
sealed class LoginRoute<out T: Any> {
    data class ToSignUp<out T : Any>(val data: T) : LoginRoute<T>()
    data class ToUserDetails<out T : Any>(val data: T) : LoginRoute<T>()
    data class ToSomeOtherPossibleDestination<out T : Any>(val data: T) : LoginRoute<T>()
}
```

Now on in `ViewModel` I can have:

```
val proceedToDestination = MutableLiveData<Event<LoginRoute>>()
```

then in the view, I could just observe `proceedToDestination` and do the following:

```
viewModel.proceedToDestination.observe(this, Observer { route ->
    route?.consume()?.run {
        when (route) {
            LoginRoute.ToSignUp -> // TODO START SIGNUP
            LoginRoute.ToUserDetails-> // TODO GO TO USER DETAILS SCREEN
            LoginRoute.ToSomeOtherPossibleDestination-> // TODO GO TO OTHER POSSIBLE DESTINATIONS
        }
    }
})
```

My question is whether this is a good idea or a good practice overall? Thanks in advance.

Edit:

Just really want to make this alive again and maybe find some answers.

Comment: Is it intentional to not subclass the sealed class `LoginRoute` with `ToSignUp` etc?

Comment: I'm not sure whether i understand your question or not. can you elaborate on that?

Comment: @ArchieG.Quiñones is it works? what is Event  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About `sealed class` - This is fine. I uploaded our [Simple-Router](https://github.com/SparingSoftware/Android-Router) approach which uses similar Routes. You can also benchmark with pretty interesting [Kompass](https://github.com/sellmair/kompass) router.

Apart from implementation the difference here is in routing responsibility - in solutions I presented `Presenter/ViewModel` has access to `Router` and calls `navigate(..)` on it - in your approach you use `Rx/LiveData` and let your `View` handle it but this it's just another logic layer above it.